# SQL duplicates with percentage result

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, percentage

I have an issue where my database contains a table with these columns:

```
Program_ID, Vehicle_VIN, Vehicle_Type
```

I need to create a report where will be:

```
Program_ID, AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram, PercentageDuplicatesInProgram

where Vehicle_type = 10
```

and criteria for the duplicate is to have `Vehicle_VIN` more than 1 unique time in the table for dedicated Program_ID.

It's in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram is:

```
SELECT 
    PROGRAM_ID, COUNT(*) AS AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram 
FROM 
    dbo.table 
WHERE
    Vehicle_type = 10 
GROUP BY 
    PROGRAM_ID
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: How do you compute "AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram"?

Comment: 1/ Microsoft SQL
2/ AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram is: 

SELECT PROGRAM_ID, COUNT(*) as AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram
FROM dbo.table
where Vehicle_type = 10
group by PROGRAM_ID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand you correctly, but you can count distinct `Vehicle_VIN` and use the `having` clause to test if the count of distinct `Vehicle_VIN` is larger than 1. Like so,

```
SELECT PROGRAM_ID, COUNT(*) as AmountOfAllPoliciesInProgram, count(distinct Vehicle_VIN) as VIN_COUNT 
FROM dbo.table 
where Vehicle_type = 10 
group by PROGRAM_ID
having count(distinct Vehicle_VIN)>1
```